# Azure blob: upload directory content using a loop in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to use a loop for uploading some files to a blob container. i.e.files xaa,xab,xac

I have tried the following loop but no success

```
import string    
for i in string.lowercase[0:2]:
        block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
            'my_container',
            'xa%s' % i,
            '/pathtomylocalfile/xa%s' % i)
```

while this works

```
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
            'my_container',
            'xaa',
            '/pathtomylocalfile/xaa')
```

Comment: You have any errors with the first approach?

Comment: no just standing by with no network trafic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise, you can try to use `format` function to format your string:

```
...
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
            'my_container',
            'xa{}'.format(i),
            '/pathtomylocalfile/xa{}'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange that seems to work as an alternative

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('/mylocaldirectory/') if isfile(join('/mylocaldirectory/', f))]

for i in onlyfiles:
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
        'mycontainer',
        '%s' % i,
        '/mylocaldirectory/%s' % i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import os

    FILE_PATH1="/pathtomylocalfile"
    container_name ='my_container'

    local_path=os.path.expanduser(FILE_PATH1)

    for root, dirs, allfiles in os.walk(FILE_PATH1):
        print(root)

        for f in allfiles:
            print(os.path.join(root, f))

            local_file_name = f

            full_path_to_file =os.path.join(root, local_file_name)


            if full_path_to_file.find(".") != False:
                print("Temp file = " + full_path_to_file)
                print("\nUploading to Blob storage as blob " + local_file_name)


                block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, full_path_to_file[1:], full_path_to_file)
```